Problems using Qcmbr to communicate with QCA6174 via the ath10k driver
I would like to use the tool Qcmbr under Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS with kernel version 5.15.0-124-generic to communicate with the QCA6174 via the ath10k driver. When using this tool, I get the following error when processing commands:
SocketRead() return 60 bytes
>>>> Diag packet received of type 75(subsystemDispatch) Len[60]
processTLVPacket - RspLen [4096]
cmd_init Beg..
cmd_init Socket[5] ret[0]..
arSendCmd2->cmd_send2 RspLen [4096]
cmd_send2 bufLen[40] rspLen[4096]..Beg
**Qcmbr: ioctl: No such device**

Now I have read that nl80211, cfg80211 and mac80211 no longer use ioctl but netlink.
My question is therefore whether the kernel modules cfg80211 and mac80211 and the interface nl80211 are backwards compatible, and can still use ioctrl?

My assumption would be that I'm using nl80211, mac80211, cfg80211 that strongly depend on the netlink systemcall. However, if I'm running Qcmbr I'm sending ioctrl systemcalls that are consequently failing as they are no longer supported. If this assumption is correct, how can I still use the tool Qcmbr to fix the above error message?
I am very grateful for every hint and thank you in advance for your support

What I've tried so far:
I compiled the tool Qcmbr and executed it on my linux machine. However, if Qcmbr is receiving and forwarding a command I'm getting the above shown error message. I had a glance at the corresponding source code and noticed that there is an ioctl-function being executed on forwarding the commands. I'm assuming that nl80211, cfg80211 and mac80211 no longer use ioctl and Qcmbr fails.
I also installed Ubuntu 14.04.6 with kernel 4.4.0-148-generic and hoped that the older kernel is supporting ioctl system calls for nl80211, cfg80211 and mac80211. However, I am still getting the same error messages as shown above.
